# How to select an unordered list in Selenium using C#

Tags: selenium-webdriver, c#

I had been having a problem trying to select an item in a dropdown. I have checked resources online but I still couldn't get it working. My HTML is this:

```
<div id="dropdownID">
<ul class="ulList">
<li class="liItem"> Number 1 </li>
<li class="liItem"> Number 2 </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

while my selenium C# is:

```
    var drop = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownId")).FindElement(By.Xpath("//ul/li[(@class='liItem') and contains(text(),'{0}')]")).click();
drop.SendKeys(value);
```

Where {value} is a string that I would like to input on sendkeys. The error would be:

```
no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//ul/li[(@class='liItem') and contains(text(),'{0}')]"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with the selector indeed.

**Issue 1**

When using XPath in the context of another element (as you are doing), always start the XPath with a dot (which represent the element you are starting from). For example, `.//ul/li`

**Issue 2**
You haven't formatted your variable text into your XPath, it says `{0}`.
So first do a `string.Format` on your XPath, then pass that as the locator value.

```
var xpath = string.Format(".//li[contains(text(),'{0}')]", "Number 1");
var drop = Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownId")).FindElement(By.Xpath(xpath)).click();
drop.SendKeys(value);
```

Comment: Ok, sorry. I have added a thread.sleep before the var xpath. thanks so much @FDM! I have added .//ul//li too though to avoid the invalid xpath expression

Answer (score 2):

***Note***: in this answer, `DivElement` represents `Driver.FindElement(By.Id("dropdownID"))`.

You can locate the first unordered list item by XPath with the following:
a. `DivElement.FindElement(By.XPath(".//li"))`
b. `DivElement.FindElements(By.XPath(".//li")).ElementAt(0)`

Moreover, you can find this item by:
1. ***Class Name***
a. `DivElement.FindElement(By.ClassName("liItem"))`
b. `DivElement.FindElements(By.ClassName("liItem")).ElementAt(0)`
2. ***Tag Name***
a. `DivElement.FindElement(By.TagName("li"))`
b. `DivElement.FindElements(By.TagName("li")).ElementAt(0)`
3. ***CSS Selector***
a. `DivElement.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".liItem"))`
b. `DivElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector(".liItem")).ElementAt(0)`